# Policy Management

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

i have a domain controller and i have added a ADMX file in :/Windows/PolicyDefinitions and a ADMl file in :/Windows/PolicyDefinitions/en-US
and when i am opening the policy manager and editing the default domain policy these two files are not visible under the admin templates, i checked this with my friend and saw in his test machine it shows Administrative templates:Policy definitions(ADMX files) retrieved from the local computer while my test machine shows retrieved from central store, my machine is 2008 R2.
please someone help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can (and you should) create a Central Store to store the administrative templates, here is the documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3087759/how-to-create-and-manage-the-central-store-for-group-policy-administrative-templates-in-Windows

With the central store, you can put your ADML/ADMX files in a single location and they will be available from all your computers (the files in the central store are retrieved by the Group Policy editor automatically).